# If I run the following script, will my ssh session not be terminated?

Tags: python, bash, ssh

So I wrote this script called py_script.py that I ran over an ssh session on a school machine:

```
import time
import os

while True:
  os.system("echo still_alive")
  time.sleep(60)
```

... by doing:

`bash $ python py_script.py &`.

Is this going to prevent the dreaded `broken pipe` message from happening?

The problem is, after a period of inactivity when I am over an ssh connection, my connection will be dropped. To prevent this, I wrote the above script that automatically writes a message to the console to count for an "action" so that I don't have to press enter every 5 minutes. (I'm idle on a machine and need to run a process for a good amount of time.)

Comment: Yes, this will work… although you could have just used a one-liner shell script, like `while true; do echo alive; sleep 60; done`. And it's probably not what you want to do anyway. (Do you really want "still_alive" randomly spewed out in your console in the middle of the output of your useful programs?)

Comment: I see what you're saying. However, the solution below hadn't worked for me in the past so I thought I'd do something like this. Essentially, what I wanted to know is if doing anything with a program running in the background (e.g. "cd .") was going to keep the session alive.

Comment: It depends on why the session is being closed… I can't promise that what you're doing (triggering output from the session back over the wire) will keep it alive, but running a program in the background that doesn't even do that would be even less likely to work.

Answer (score 4):

If your connection is timing out then it is more advisable to look at SSH configuration options which can keep your connection alive.

As a starter example, put the following in a file called `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host *
ServerAliveInterval 20
TCPKeepAlive=yes
```

You can read more [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Client_Configuration_Files).